# pushViewController not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have an application which has a view called store. In this view there is a button which loads the DetailView. Problem is that this detailview doesn't load/show. This is the code I use:

```
-(void)knop:(id)sender{
    categoryView = [[CategoryView alloc] init];
    //show detail view using buttonDetail...
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:categoryView animated:YES];
    [categoryView release];
    NSLog(@"Button is working");
}
```

The log "Button is working" logs, so the pushViewController line is also triggered.

categoryView is made in my .h file:

```
 CategoryView IBOutlet *categoryView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CategoryView *categoryView;
```

In the store.xib there is a UIViewController with an outlet linked to the categoryView outlet.

Somewhere else in my app this is working, and I can't seem to find out why this one isn't

Any help would be appreciated!
THNX

Comment: is `CategoryView` an UIView or UIViewController. The pushViewController method will only work with UIViewControllers. Also is there an UINavigationController which holds the `categoryView` viewCointroller?

Comment: It's an UIViewController: @interface CategoryView : UIViewController{

Comment: Is your 'root' viewController in UINSvigationController?

Comment: I only have UIViewController, should I place a UINavigationController in the store.xib then?

Comment: What type of app you are using ? Is it Navigation Based or Tab bar based ?

Comment: What's the point of having a `categoryView` property? In the example code a local variable in the `knop` method would suffice...

Comment: You right, there is no point. Will change that

Comment: Do you have a navigation bar at all? Also, naming controllers like views is misleading at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found it. Since I was using a tabbar based app, I needed to change the store tab to Navigation Controller. When I changed it, it worked! Thanks for all your support!!!

Comment: I think I have the exact same problem. Could you elaborate on what you mean with this answer?

Comment: Okey, well in your main.xib. You probably have declared which views you are having... This is the xib where your tabbar itself is located. You just need to select your view and make sure it's a navigationcontroller

Comment: Oh, ok. But that would mean that my buttons and table view won't show as those are part of the view I want to load. Where did you move your view contents after replacing with the navigationController?

Comment: The navigationController is a controller. You can have different kinds of views in here. For example a UITableView... The controller is just a container for all the view but extends it with the navigation options.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I'll have to redesign my approach as I'm now loading an empty navigationView instead of my old customView when starting the app.

Answer (score 12):

Did you assign the UINavigationController in your AppDelegate?

@interface

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet RootViewController *rootViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

@implementation didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootView" bundle:nil];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

pushViewController works fine then through the whole App.

Comment: This wil remove my tabbar and insert a navigation bar at top.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like

```
NSLog(@"nav controller = %@", self.navigationController);
```

will show that navigationController is nil.

I suggest creating a new project of navigation type and see how this should be setup.

Comment: It does come up with null. I will try your suggestions

Comment: At the moment I have allocated a UINavigation controller in the store class and the log isn't logging null now. Sadly it does not push the other viewcontroller CategoryView. Any ideas?

Comment: app delegate, applicationDidFinishLoading: what is being set to the root view controller?

Answer (score 1):

If your view is nib based, you need to use:

```
categoryView = [[CategoryView alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
```

Hope this helps.